# XAMPP PHP 5.6 and mongoDB : cannot recognize mongo driver

Tags: php, apache, mongodb, dll, xampp

I installed XAMPP-Win32-5.6.11-0-VC11. In phpinfo() I can see that :

PHP Version : 5.6.11

PHP Extension Build : API20131226,TS,VC11

Apache Version : Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1m PHP/5.6.11

I downloaded PHP mongo drivers from here : [Drivers](https://s3.amazonaws.com/drivers.mongodb.org/php/index.html)

The zip files I have downloaded are :

php_mongo-1.6.4.zip
 php_mongo-1.6.5.zip
 php_mongo-1.6.6.zip
 php_mongo-1.6.7.zip
 php_mongo-1.6.8.zip

I tried :

php_mongo-1.*.*-5.6-vc11.dll

php_mongo-1.*.*-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll

These 2 dll files but none of them worked. In phpinfo() I can't see the mongo extension. If I try to use nts(Not Thread Safe) files I get php5.dll not found error when I restart Apache server.

Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: I tried every zips' php_mongo-ZİP_NUMBER -5.6-vc11.dll and  php_mongo-ZİP_NUMBER -5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll  files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I finnaly solved the problem. When I had this problem I was using the xampp I dowloaded and it was the latest version.(xampp-win32-5.6.11-0-VC11-installer.exe) but I tried and older version(xampp-win32-5.5.27-0-VC11-installer.exe) and after going through same steps it all worked out. Now I can see mongo in my phpinfo() screen.

Comment: HI, so you mean to say that mongodb extention is not valid for php5.6, i am also facing the same issue. i tried with xampp php 5.3 and 5.6, pssible will check now with 5.5 as u suggest above

Answer (score 1):

Okay 1.6.10 is out. Check PECL.

http://pecl.php.net/package/mongo

And try this:

http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/mongo/1.6.10/php_mongo-1.6.10-5.6-ts-vc11-x86.zip

Comment: I downloaded the zip file and tried it still mongo extension is not showing in phpinfo

Comment: after putting php_mongo.dll to xampp\php\ext I restarted server and there were no errors. I run the phpinfo and extension is not there.

Comment: I'll try to install an older version of xampp and try again now.

Comment: it prints PHP modules and mongo is not in them

Comment: Oh wait I run it again and I can see mongo. So why is it not in phpinfo()?

Comment: Yes. The file you are editing is loaded by PHP-CLI but not apache handler. Look for other php.ini in xampp/apache folder, add the same line in that. the phpinfo() must have loaded configuration file.

Comment: in xampp/apache folder or in any subfolder in xampp/apche there are no php.ini or any php named files. Should I add one? or copy the php.ini

Comment: wait. check `Loaded Configuration File` in phpinfo().

Comment: it is xampp\php\php.ini this file which is the php file that I added the extensin=php_mongo.dll line.

Comment: Okay. Sorry. I give up. I really can't say why php-cli was able to load and not apache handler. :D

Comment: Thank you for your answers :) İnteresting thing is when I remove an extension from php.ini file I can see it removed from phpinfo but when I run php -m it's still there. I'll try to find a solution :)